# How to get special solution with DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the following ODE with DSolve, but can't obtain a special solution (which I know exists simply by looking at the equation: f[x]=1)

```
a[x_] = f[x] /. 
  DSolve[{m f[x]^(3/2) f'[x] + 2 k f'[x]^2 - 2 k f[x] f''[x] == 0}, f[x], x]
Solve[a[0] == 1, C[1]]
```

The Solve parts simply gives me empty brackets.

If I include the boundary condition in DSolve I only get the error message "For some branches of the solution, unable to solve the conditions".

I know this is similar to other questions here, but I wasn't able to use the corresponding answers for my problem.

How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `DSolve` is a list

```
DSolve[{m f[x]^(3/2) f'[x] + 2 k f'[x]^2 - 2 k f[x] f''[x] == 0}, 
 f[x], x]
```

> 

```
{{f[x] -> (
   E^(x C[1] + C[1] C[2]) k^2 C[
    1]^2)/(-1 + E^((x C[1])/2 + (C[1] C[2])/2) m)^2}, {f[x] -> (
   E^(x C[1] + C[1] C[2]) k^2 C[
    1]^2)/(1 + E^((x C[1])/2 + (C[1] C[2])/2) m)^2}}
```

In order to define functions it is better to use `Part` like so:

```
a1[x_] = 
 f[x] /. DSolve[{m f[x]^(3/2) f'[x] + 2 k f'[x]^2 - 2 k f[x] f''[x] ==
       0}, f[x], x][[1]]
a2[x_] = 
 f[x] /. DSolve[{m f[x]^(3/2) f'[x] + 2 k f'[x]^2 - 2 k f[x] f''[x] ==
       0}, f[x], x][[2]]
```

Now we can move on and ask Mathematica to `Solve`

```
Solve[a[0] == 1, C[1]]
```

and it complains a bit

> `This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

We can use assumptions to get

```
Assuming[k != 0, Solve[(a1[0] /. C[2] -> 0) == 1, C[1]]]
```

> `{{C[1] -> (1 - m)/k}, {C[1] -> (-1 + m)/k}}`

Without assumptions, further progress can be made with the use of `Reduce`

```
Reduce[a1[0] == 1, C[1]]
```

giving

> `(-1 + m != 0 && k != 0 &&  C[2] == 0 && (C[1] == (-1 + m)/k || C[1] == (1 - m)/k)) || (C[ 3] \[Element] Integers &&  C[2] != 0 && -1 + E^((C[1] C[2])/2) m != 0 &&  k != 0 && (C[1] == ( m C[2] +  2 k ProductLog[C[3], -((E^(-((m C[2])/(2 k))) C[2])/(2 k))])/( k C[2]) ||  C[1] == (-m C[2] +  2 k ProductLog[C[3], (E^((m C[2])/(2 k)) C[2])/(2 k)])/( k C[2])))`

Answer (score 2):

The following goes some way towards a solution, by using `Reduce`, and by including all parameters in the solution in the list of variables to be solved for:

```
sol = DSolve[m f[x]^(3/2) f'[x] + 2 k f'[x]^2 - 2 k f[x] f''[x] == 0, f[x], x]
Reduce[f[x] == 1 /. sol /. x -> 0, {C[1], C[2], k, m}]

(* Out:
C[1] != 0 && (k == -(1/(Sqrt[E^(C[1]*C[2])]*C[1])) || 
   k == 1/(Sqrt[E^(C[1]*C[2])]*C[1])) && m == 0
*)
```